# Rally App SDK 2.0: rallymultiobjectpicker for users not showing displayField

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I am attempting to create a rallymultiobjectpicker that lists the users of a workspace. However, it does not seem to load any values for the displayField, regardless of what it is set to in the listCfg. The documentation specifies that the default is "Name," to which I have switched around to "FirstName," "ObjectID", "DisplayName," "_refObjectName," etc. No changes seem to be reflected, as the divs that should contain the values for the displayField remain empty. I have checked the objects, and here is an example of what is typically returned (all empty fields are generated and not modified):

```
->Object
    CreationDate: null
    Disabled: false
    DisplayName: ""
    EmailAddress: ""
    FirstName: ""
    LastName: ""
    LastPasswordUpdateDate: null
    MiddleName: ""
    ObjectID: 1234567890
    OnpremLdapUsername: ""
    RevisionHistory: ""
    Role: ""
    ShortDisplayName: ""
    Subscription: ""
    TeamMemberships: ""
    UserName: ""
    UserPermissions: ""
    UserProfile: ""
    _objectVersion: "12"
    _p: "2"
    _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/1.33/user/1234567890.js"
    _refObjectName: "John D"
    _type: "user"
    creatable: false
    deletable: false
    groupSelected: "Available"
    matchedText: undefined
    updatable: true
    __proto__: Object
```

Here is an example of the code used:

```
Ext.widget('rallymultiobjectpicker', {
    modelType: 'user',
    fieldLabel: 'Owners',
    listCfg: {displayField: "DisplayName", autoScroll: true},
    stateful: false,
    labelWidth: 50,
});
```

**EDIT**: Using a similar configuration as the one listed in the answer below, this issue has arisen again in 2.0p3. There is no option text shown, despite having the displayField specified in the listCfg. I should also note that the filters/customQuery seem to be completely broken, as they don't function to limit the data set I have in another rallymultiobjectpicker.

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a data store configuration that fetches the displayField from the server. You'll have to specify the entire store configuration, not only the fetch parameter. You'll also have to pass a config option for the filterFieldName for the auto complete functionality to work properly. An example configuration is below:

```
Ext.widget('rallymultiobjectpicker', {
    modelType: 'user',
    fieldLabel: 'Owners',
    filterFieldName: 'DisplayName',
    storeCfg: {
        autoLoad: false,
        fetch: 'DisplayName',
        pageSize: 200,
        sorters: [
            {
                property: 'DisplayName',
                direction: 'ASC'
            }
        ],
        remoteGroup: false,
        remoteSort: false,
        remoteFilter: false,
        limit: Infinity
    },
    listCfg: {
        displayField: 'DisplayName'
    },
    stateful: false,
    labelWidth: 50
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. However, I am having trouble with disabled users showing up, regardless of whether I specify a filter for only those who are not disabled: filters: [
         {
          property: 'Disabled',
          value: 'false'
         }
        ] I have also tried specifying "false" without the quotes.

Comment: Another issue I'm having is figuring out how to filter by UsePermissions, since it is an array of UserPermission.

Comment: There is a bug where the storeCfg filters are cleared every time the data store is reset. For now, you will have to add Disabled to the fetch values and you can specify a customQuery.  fetch: ['DisplayName', 'Disabled'], customQuery: '(Disabled = true)'